# Having problems with pip in Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

Installing pip has been notoriously difficult for me. I still have not figured it out even after several attempts with different tutorials.
I have been trying to use pip (for beginner Python projects) but have had to abandon the projects as pip is not working for me. Sometimes I think I have successfully installed pip, but then I get:

> C:\Python33>pip

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I tried another tutorial, ran this, and got:

> C:\Python33>get-pip.py

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python33\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.3.egg
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |################################| 71kB 264kB/s
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.29.0
```

The problem is I keep getting:

> C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages>pip

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How to install pip here? I have Python 3.3.3 and Windows

Comment: add `pip` to `PATH`

Comment: `C:\Users>py -m pip install requests` try this command if it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a python interpreter...Try this:

```
import pip

pip.main(["install","--User", "package"]) 
# so...
pip.main(["install", "--Trump", "cython"])
# also if no user specified, usually this is my go to
pip.main(["install", "cython"])
```

Comment: Thanks. It finally worked after I ran cd to scripts in the python directory

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
python -m pip install <package_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try python distributions with built-in libraries. Since you are a windows user , you can use Winpython for example, https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/ which is a portable Windows distribution of Python. I'm using it since it already includes most of the scientific and numerical libraries and there's also a built-in package installer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like PIP is not in your PATH system variables, so cmd will not recognize it as internal command.

To check is it true type `echo %PATH%` at the CMD prompt. PIP should be installed to `C:\Python33\Scripts\pip` normally, if you dont see line like this after entering `echo %PATH%`, you need to add path to pip to PATH system variables manually from control panel or cmd with `setx` command. For instance:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python33\Scripts"
```

If you  want to add path to PIP from control panel use [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/), it should help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to consult this link : 
[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) wich contains the answer to your question, I have noticed that you use python33 so you can go directly to [this link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip) (the 2nd link I proposed to you is from the page of the 1st link), I hope this will help you.

Comment: Instead of refer links, you can put your own explication :)

Comment: Sometimes I'm in rush but I love to help others, so I look for the shortest way to help ;) , thanks for the advice.